# padding issue - bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have a look at the below example in `Mobile` mode.

[Sample](http://www.bootply.com/10SXxmv9Xf#)

In `Fieldset 3`, why is there a slight `padding` on the left for all the labels and textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the below answer states, you have given `col-md-6` class along with your `form-group` for *Fieldset 3*. Now since you do  need the `col-md-6` to separate the elements into 2 columns, you could target that specific fieldset and remove the padding.

HTML:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="fieldset3"> <!-- ID added -->
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Fieldset 3</legend>
```

CSS:

```
#fieldset3 .col-md-6{
  padding-left:0px;
}
```

**[DEMO 1](http://www.bootply.com/uEfrsDSU5K)**

To make it easier you can also group the labels this way:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Label and input here -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Label and input here -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Label and input here -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Label and input here -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Label and input here -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Label and input here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO 2](http://www.bootply.com/6qDEPgW1Gm#)**

Answer (score 2):

Cause you nestind classes for columns. First you have `div.col-md-6.form-group`, and inside you have `label.control-label.col-md-8`, so it doubles the padding for `col-*`.